# error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant when using character data type

Tags: c, compiler-errors, switch-statement, syntax-error, character

This is the projects 4 of Chapter 7:Basic Types I am trying to do in the book "C Programming: A Modern Approach(2nd version)".
The question looks like this:
[Question description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9bf9.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(){
    char apb;
    int num;
    printf("Enter phone number:");
    do{
    apb = getchar();
    apb = toupper(apb);
    while(apb != ' ' || apb != '\n'){
        switch(apb){
            case 'A': case'B': case "C":
                printf("2");break;
            case 'D': case'E': case "F":
                printf("3");break;
            ...
            case 'Y': case'W': case "X":
                printf("9");break;
            default:printf("Error:please try again\n");
        }
    }
}while{apb >='A' && apb <='Z'};
    return 0; 
}
```

when i try to compile the code, *the compiler threw a error* for every part for my case label saying that:

> "[Error]case label does not reduce to an integer constant".

it made me kinda for curious that what kind of mistake that i have made as i see no error in **using a constant character type** as a case label. Is it about the version of compiler that i am using?

Comment: one line for one `case` and don't use `"`in the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case 'A': case'B': case "C":
```

While `'A'` and `'B'` are characters, `"C"` is a character *pointer* so cannot be used.

You need to use `'C'` instead. Ditto for `F` and `X`.